# CRM Javascript lookup

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-online

I have some JavaScript that runs when the `ContactId` is changed on a Custom Entity and populates the fax number field from the Contacts entity into `mh_fax` field of the custom entity. This code works fine:

```
 function contact_onchange () {
    // get contactid 
    var vContactid =  Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("mh_contactid").getValue()[0].id;
    try { var Fax= getAttributeValue (vContactid , "contact", "contactid", "fax",   false); }   catch (e) {  }
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("mh_fax").setValue(Fax);
   }
```

I am trying to write similar code to run when the parentcontactid field is updated on the Leads entity, but this code does not work.

```
 function contact_onchange () {
    // -----get contactid 
    var vContactid =  Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("parentcontactid").getValue()[0].id;
    alert(vContactid)
    try { var Fax= getAttributeValue (vContactid , "contact", "contactid", "fax",   false); }   catch (e) {  }
    alert (Fax);
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("telephone1").setValue(Fax);
    }
```

The 1st alert that I have inserted in the code, shows that `vContactid` is being set to the correct value.
The problem seems to be with the "`Fax= getAttributeValue` " line, as the 2nd alert returns undefined and "telephone1 field is blanked out.

Can anyone see why this code works for a custom entity but not for the Leads entity?

Thanks

Comment: can you update your post with `getAttributeValue` method body? Also I am assuming the record does have a `fax` number?

Comment: Yes, the record does have a fax number.

Comment: Thanks @Sayuri - Yes, the record does have a fax number.   I thought that getAttributeVaue was an inbuilt function, but you are right this must be a custom function. The original java code on the entity where the code works was written by a consultant. I have looked at all the Form libraries that load with the form where the code works but can't find the function getAttributeValue. Do you know where else this function could be declared?

Comment: I have found the function GetAttributeValue:  function getAttributeValue(lookupValue, entityName, attributeName, queryAttrName, isReturnId) 
{
var queryReturnValue;
var queryOptions = {
entityName: entityName,
attributes: [attributeName],
values: [lookupValue],
columnSet: [queryAttrName] 
};
var fetchedEntities = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.QueryByAttribute(queryOptions);
if(fetchedEntities.length >= 1) {
if(isReturnId==false)
{
queryReturnValue = fetchedEntities[0].attributes[queryAttrName].value;
}

Comment: else
{ 
queryReturnValue = fetchedEntities[0].attributes[queryAttrName].id;
}
}
return queryReturnValue;
}

Comment: I then added the GetAttributeValue.js and the XRMServiceToolkit.min to the form libraries (still can't see these on the other form that works!!!). All functions now run and correct data is returned. Thanks for you help in pointing me in the right direction.